# WordPress How to create custom (Resume) page url slug + author id slug

Tags: php, wordpress, slug, author

I have created custom page ( Resume / CV ) template for our users, to display their informations like "avatar, name, description..etc

I got the users information by using `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();`

each user when he visit this page he can see his informations only! But what if I need this page to be public same as `author.php`, all users can see the resume/cv of each other.

So now the page URL is `https://www.website.com/resume/`

And i need this page to be `https://www.website.com/resume/?author=id`

There are any options to get the user data instead of `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();` to make this page public for all!

> **Update 1**

Resume page template

```
<?php 
/**
 * Template Name: Resume Page
 */

$user = FALSE;
if (!empty($_GET['author'])) {
   $user = get_user_by('ID',$_GET['author']);
} else  {
   $user = wp_get_current_user();
}

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

          <div class="pic"><?php echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 200 ); ?></div>
          <span class="first-name"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></span>
          <span class="subtitle"><?php echo $user->profession; ?></span>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

I'm trying now to add href link inside `author.php` but it always return page not found! 
So how can i create link belong to the author id to be easy for anyone to see the user Resume?

```
<?php 
if ( is_user_logged_in() ):
    echo '<div class="user-resume">';
    echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/resume/?author=";
    echo $curauth->ID;
    echo "\">";
    echo "See full resume";
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</div>";
endif;
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is `https://www.website.com/resume/?author=id`

> **Update 2**

`author.php` file

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php
    $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
    ?>

    <?php echo $curauth->first_name .' '. $curauth->last_name; ?>
    <?php echo get_avatar( $curauth->ID, 200 ); ?>
    // and so on...

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: Yeah, there are options...you could use `$_GET['author']` and pass the id to `get_user_meta` or where ever you store the user information.

Comment: Thanks @disinfor, I'm still newbie with WP, Kindly can you show me a small example.

Comment: If you want help, post some of the PHP code you use now. This is less WP and more PHP related.

Comment: Thanks @disinfor, I updated my question, Kindly check.

Comment: I think there's a big piece missing: how do you expect your users to know `?author=$id`? Do you have a page with all the users names listed out that people can click on one to take them to their resume page? I'm not sure how you expect users to get to a specific resume.

Comment: mmm did you mean author.php? I really don't know how can i explain what I'm trying to do but I'll try.. each user has his own profile (`author.php`) and anyone can see the other user profile's whatever logged in users or visitors! Then I created custom page template ( Resume) the page url is `www.site.com/resume`, So how can i add href link inside author.php to be  linked with each user resume and public to anyone to see the other user resume! and I just guessed that  if I added author id at the end of page url it will work! `www.site.com/resume/?author=$id`, did you get it :(

Comment: Ah! Yes, that makes sense now. I'll see what I can come up with to help you. :) Post your `author.php` page as well in your question. I want to see that code too.

Comment: Thanks so much @disinfor for your support, I updated my question.

Comment: Hello @disinfor, I don't mean to bother you, but there are any updates? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the an author parameter is passed and query the user based on ID passed in that parameter. If no parameter is passed, it will query the current user that is logged in.

```
$user = FALSE;
if (!empty($_GET['author']) {
   $user = get_user_by('ID',$_GET['author']);
} else  {
   $user = wp_get_current_user();
}
```

You should add more validation though to check if the ID queries a valid user or the visitor is currently logged  in as a user.

**UPDATE FOR UPDATE**

As for the link to the current user's resume, you can do the following:

```
echo site_url('/resume/?author=' . get_current_user_id());
```

Comment: Thanks so much @DominickNavarro, Kindly check the updated question, is this the right way?

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I still get page not found :( Please check this link, I added See Full Resume link inside the user info tab, https://www.cgartzone.com/profile/yanoo-max/

Comment: I think you missunderstand me, I don't need to create author page! I already have one! I created custom page template called "resume", then I need to add href link inside the author page and when any one visit any user profile he will find button to see the resume of this user,  I hope i explained it well :(

Comment: How can i make the resume page public to everyone,  so i can see the other users resume :(